# how to auto-paste text in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, searchbar

I have searchbar in my table view I want to auto search or auto-paste text in search bar when we have copied text

can I do it?

it is source code

import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

```
var listEnWord = [EnWordModel]()
var filteredWord = [EnWordModel]()
var inSearchMode = false
var dbHelper = DatabaseHelper()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchaWord()
    loadAllWords()

  }

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}

func loadAllWords(){
    listEnWord = dbHelper.getAllEnWord()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    }


func searchaWord(){
    let searchBar = UISearchBar()
    self.view.addSubview (searchBar)
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
}


func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if inSearchMode {
        return filteredWord.count
    }

    return listEnWord.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! ItemMenuCell

    if inSearchMode {
        cell.enword = filteredWord[indexPath.row]

    } else {

        cell.enword = listEnWord[indexPath.row]

    }

    return cell
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        inSearchMode = false
        tableView.reloadData()
        self.view.endEditing(true)

    } else {

        inSearchMode = true
        let lower = searchBar.text!.lowercased()
        filteredWord = listEnWord.filter({$0.Word?.range(of: lower, options: .anchored ) != nil})
        tableView.reloadData()
        tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if inSearchMode {
      Singleton.ShareInstance.enwordSelected = filteredWord[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        Singleton.ShareInstance.enwordSelected = listEnWord[indexPath.row]
    }

    let des = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailController")
    navigationController?.pushViewController(des!, animated: true )
}
```

}

thanks for helping me

Answer (score 2):

Sure, seems like you are looking for a way to auto search text in your clipboard. So first register clipboard text change listener in this way. Note that it only works within your application:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(clipboardChanged),
                                       name: NSNotification.Name.UIPasteboardChanged , object: nil)
```

Then handle the it by this function

```
func clipboardChanged(){
    let pasteboardString: String? = UIPasteboard.general.string
    if let theString = pasteboardString {
        print("String is \(theString)")
        // Put the string into your search bar and do the search
    }
}
```